# Is "simpatico" a synonym of "same"?

Tags: meaning

I've come across the word **simpatico** and it aroused my curiosity, so I looked it up in the Oxford dictionary:

> - **Having or characterized by shared attributes or interests; compatible**

The usage examples include the word **relationship** after **simpatico**, which slightly perplexes me. Is this *always* the case?

Plus, based on the definition, I would assume **simpatico** is synonymous with the word **same**. Am I right?

Consider the following examples. Is **simpatico** used correctly here?

> 1. *The two companies have **simpatico** ideas for some products that can trump a myriad number of others and cause them to be out of business.*
> 2. *We had a **simpatico** **relationship** and we were the epitome of a perfect couple as we were like-minded.*

Comment: [***Simpatico***](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/more+simpatico) usually has a meaning more like *similar* or *compatible*, using the definition you gave. **Same** implies identical, where **simpatico** is usually describing compatibility.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for editing my post. Secondly, is it right to describe two phones that have almost the same features as simpatico?

Comment: I would say no. I say that because *simpatico* describes more of a harmonic relationship, like Mitch describes. You could say a marriage is simpatico, but you wouldn't necessarily use it to describe two items or people that are almost identical.

Comment: "Sympatico" is closer to the meaning of "sympathizing" than it is to "same".

Comment: @Hank; [Harmonic](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/harmonic) is not the same as 'harmonious' which would fit here.

Comment: @TimLymington I was on my phone for that comment. Didn't realize it corrected me. I used "harmonious" down below again, showing what I meant haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No 'simpatico' is not a synonym of 'same'. If you replace 'same' with 'sympatico' or the other way around, you will give a very different impression.

Their definitions seem to have something in common, but with 'simpatico' the emphasis is with a mutually endearing relationship, like between friends or colleagues that like each other. Similarity might be present, or just as well not.

'Same' means all (or most) of their properties are shared.

'Simpatico' means they work well together, which would more likely imply they  fill in gaps the others don't, rather than being similar.

Also, 'same' is a very common and very basic word with very simple semantics. 'Simpatico' is much rarer, is a bit slangy/informal (sounds like two gangsters might share a sub sandwich in New Jersey: "Let me pay for the check", "Fuggeddaboutit. We're sympatico").

Comment: Oh! thanks for the succinct explanation! I never hear anyone use the word to be honest. Is it formal? And could you tell me if the following example right or not: My father and Jake have a simpatico way of thinking.

Comment: @HoyHoy It depends on what you mean by that sentence. Does their thinking help them work harmoniously together? Or is their thinking the same? Or both?

Comment: They think similarly.

Comment: No - your father and Jake are `sympatico`, meaning they think alike . You don't need to explicitly say "their way of thinking is..."   The word is directly borrowed from Romance languages.

Comment: OMG! Finally! *cries* I literally jumped for joy. Thanks a lot!

Comment: One last question. If you are looking for making a good team, you should look up for simpatico members because if the team members don't think alike, the team is more likely to achieve nothing! Was the usage of simpatico right?

Comment: Yes, a simpatico group would be beneficial. That group would be good at working together. They will not necessarily achieve nothing if they don't think alike, but they will achieve less if they think in opposite ways and will not budge. A **Simpatico** group can think differently but still work together harmoniously, meaning their different (or similar) thinking patterns work well together.

Comment: *Simpático* just means that which inspires sympathy, so for people it means charming, agreeable, and nice easy-going folks.

Comment: "My father and Jake have a simpatico way of thinking." if it is intended to mean simply 'similar' then no that's not right. (simpatico probably implies similar, but not necessarily). 'simpatico' actually implies that they are not identical but that the get along well together and maybe _complement_ each other (filling gaps that the other has).

Comment: "you should look for simpatico members" means that the members get along well together. They may be all the same or they may complement each other in an agreeable way.. You should not use 'simpatico' as an interesting replacement for 'same' or 'similar'; that would give misleading extra meanings that are not there.

Comment: 'simpatico' is pretty informal

Comment: So,  did this re-enter from Italian americans or Hispanic americans?  It is interesting to see the slight differences in how Italian and Spanish seem to use the root word.  In Italian it looks like it retains more of the sympathetic idea of someone likely to share your concerns(or share each others) ... in Spanish, it has come to be synonymous with 'friendly' and 'good' which, to me, indicates a high value that hispanic cultures using the word that way value someone with sympathy of concerns.